# In CDK, why is a Lambda Function's Role Optional? What is the idiomatic way to grant permissions to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I [note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#role-1) that the `role` property of a CDK Lambda Function is of type `iam.IRole | undefined`. This is surprising to me - how is it possible for a Lambda Function to exist without a Role to act as?

In practice, this is frustrating because it means that, instead of:

```
const dynamoTable = new Table(...);
const func = new Function(...);
dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(func.role);
```

, I have to instead do

```
[...]
if (typeof func.role !== 'undefined') {
  dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(func.role);
}
```

(Though I am at least impressed that TypeScript can determine that the property is defined within that `if` block if, instead, I extract `const funcRole = func.role`)

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

---

EDIT: Balu's answer, which points out that the `Function` itself is `IGrantable`, addresses how to update the RolePolicy for the auto-created Role - but (I believe?) we still need a concrete Role in order to update Resource Policies (e.g. on Queues) by calling `resource.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({...}))` with appropriate `principals`. Some resources like Dynamo Tables have "helper" methods that can accept the Function itself - but for those that don't, the Role (or, more accurately, a `Principal`) is required.

Comment: Maybe issue with the docs? Can you actually deploy a function without a role?

Comment: No, not an issue with the docs - the CDK module itself defines the property as Optional, too. Though I suppose, to go a level deeper, it might be an issue with CDK itself...

Comment: [Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-role) is required in CloudFormation. CDK maps to CFN. Maybe CDK will out-create a role in case you don't give it yourself. CFN will fail without a role.

Comment: I am wondering this as well. I have to write a bunch of if statement in order to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 3):

CDK code, if we don't pass a role, it creates a role with default permissions `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` and `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`

From documentation:

> Lambda functions assume an IAM role during execution. In CDK by
> default, Lambda functions will use an autogenerated Role if one is not
> provided.
>
> The autogenerated Role is automatically given permissions to execute
> the Lambda function.

We can always add additional permissions by calling `addToRolePolicy` on the function.  OR by calling grant permissions on other resources like dynamoDb or loggroup, etc.

Lets say our lambda is created like this

```
const myFun = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  code: ...})
```

We can add permissions like this:

```
 myFun.role.addToRolePolicy(
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
            resources: ['*'],
            actions: [...],
        })
    );
```

OR
Lets say we want to grant access to write to log group, we can do this, which appends additional inline policy to lambda role.

```
const logGroup = new awsLogs.LogGroup(this, `my-fun`, {
    retention: 30,
    logGroupName: `/aws/lambda/${functionName}`,
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
});
logGroup.grantWrite(this.myFun);
```

Similarly in case of DynamoDB,for dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData method, we need to pass function itself, not the role. so,

Instead of

```
dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(myFun.role);
```

We should do

```
dynamoTable.grantReadWriteData(myFun);
```

Comment: Ah, it was that last line that got me! I didn't spot that the _Function_ is an `IGrantable`. Thanks!

Comment: Me in 2023: "Wow, this question perfectly describes the problem I'm currently having. That's really helpful! I wonder who wrote it.....hey, wait a second..."

Comment: Hmm, actually, no; there's still an issue. This addresses how to call `resource.grant(...)`-type methods, to update the `IGrantable`'s own IAM policies - but it still leaves us unable to update the Resource's own Resource Policy (`resource.addToResourcePolicy(new PolicyStatement{...})`), since the `principals` must be `IPrincipal`, not just `IGrantable` - and a Function is `IGrantable` but not `IPrincipal`.

I could ask a different question, but I feel this is still relevant under the original presentation - I'll make an edit, and more-experienced SO's can let me know if that's appropriate.

Comment: I hope it's not considered a breach of etiquette to remove the "acceptance" from this answer, since (as my comment, and my question-edit, point out) it does not fully answer the question. I imagine it's not getting attention because, as an apparently-answered question, it is not prioritized. Hopefully this will prompt more answers.